A problem connecting to the Informix database using DataGrip
I am using a Windows 11 system and DataGrip 2024.1.2 client to connect to the Informix server with the Informix JDBC 4.50.10 driver.
The following connection parameters were used.
jdbc:informix-sqli://IP:PORT/xx:informixserver=pnib;DBDATE=MDY4;NEWLOACLE=en_us,zh_cn,zh_tw;NEWCODESET=GB2312-80,8859-1,819,Big5,GB18030

However, an error occurred as shown in the figure below.
Error prompts during client connection
When I double-click to enter a table, the following error occurs
Error prompts during execute SQL
I changed the database driver version of Informix JDBC to 4.10.x, But this did not take effect.
Then I switched to the DBeaver client using the same settings and was able to connect to the Informix database normally.

please create a new YouTrack request with the IDE UI logs from Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

See Why should I not post images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Your second image seems to list SELECT t.* FROM cxx99.ajmldm t LIMIT 501 and cites an error -201: Syntax error.  To my considerable surprise, the notation LIMIT 501 after the FROM clause is valid in Informix, at least in recent enough versions.  Which version of the Informix server are you using?  If you're using the JDBC 4.50 driver, it should be Informix 14.10.  There are other notations in Informix, notably SELECT LIMIT 501 t.* FROM cxx99.ajmldm t (which was the notation I expected to use — fortunately, I checked the manual and tested before posting).

I wonder if the JDBC driver is parsing the SQL and generating the error, or whether the server is generating the error.  One way to check that would be to use dbaccess to run the query against your database — though I'd suggest using a smaller number than 501 for the test.  If that works, then there's a moderate chance that the problem is in the JDBC driver.  If that fails with a -201 error, it seems likely that your server is old enough not to support the LIMIT at the end of the SQL.

See projection clause and limit clause linked from the main SELECT statement manual page.

Your SQL is using the LIMIT clause near the end of the SELECT statement; in the grammar, it appears after the (optional) ORDER BY clause.  A bit of research shows that the code to allow that syntax was added in late 2013.  You have to be using a very old server for the syntax not to be recognized by the server.

First of all, I deeply appreciate your patient response. With so many answers, you must have put in a lot of effort,thank you, sir. I have read the article about not uploading images, and I will pay attention to this aspect in the future. I am a new employee at a company that uses the Informix database, Now I have asked my colleagues and learned that the version of the Informix database on this server is 11.5, which does not support the use of limit statements. Because the DataGrip client defaults to using the limit statement when querying, a syntax error occurs.

If it's convenient for you, I'd like to ask about the error in image one. Thank you again. Although the client indicates 'Failed', I can connect to the database and use query statements normally. After searching for related issues, I found that these errors are actually maybe Warnings and won't affect our normal use of query statements. The solution is you can set the command SET client_min_messages TO ERROR; is this operation correct?

This is the error message when connecting
DBMS: Informix Dynamic Server (ver. 11.50.FC9)
Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=lower
Driver: Informix JDBC Driver for Informix Dynamic Server (ver. 4.50.JC10, JDBC4.2)
Ping: 187 ms 
[01I01] Database has transactions.
[01I04] Database selected.

The 11.50 version of Informix has been out of support for a long time; so has the 11.70 version which followed it.  The standard advice is to upgrade, but I expect there are reasons why your company won't.  You can try using the notation SELECT LIMIT 501 t.* FROM cxx99.ajmldm t mentioned earlier — that was supported before the notation you used, but I'm not now sure whether that was part of 11.50 or not.

The information printed when connecting doesn't indicate any error.  The 01I01 and 01I04 values for SQLCODE are informative rather than errors.  Indeed, the fact that the code can identify that the database has transactions means it connected, and the "Database selected" message also indicates that the connection was successful.  Also, you'd not get the -201 syntax error message if you'd not been able to connect to the database.

Thank you very much for your answer! I understand the reasons behind these phenomena.

Transferring comments into an answer.
Your second image seems to list SELECT t.* FROM cxx99.ajmldm t LIMIT 501 and cites an error -201: Syntax error. To my considerable surprise, the notation LIMIT 501 after the FROM clause is valid in Informix, at least in recent versions. Which version of the Informix server are you using? If you're using the JDBC 4.50 driver, it should be Informix 14.10. There are other notations in Informix, notably SELECT LIMIT 501 t.* FROM cxx99.ajmldm t (which was the notation I expected to use — fortunately, I checked the manual and tested before posting).
I wonder if the JDBC driver is parsing the SQL and generating the error, or whether the server is generating the error. One way to check that would be to use dbaccess to run the query against your database — though I'd suggest using a smaller number than 501 for the test. If that works, then there's a moderate chance that the problem is in the JDBC driver. If that fails with a -201 error, it seems likely that your server is old enough not to support the LIMIT at the end of the SQL.
See projection clause and limit clause linked from the main SELECT statement manual page.
Your SQL is using the LIMIT clause near the end of the SELECT statement; in the grammar, it appears after the (optional) ORDER BY clause. A bit of research shows that the code to allow that syntax was added in late 2013. You have to be using a very old server for the syntax not to be recognized by the server.

The version of the Informix database on this server is 11.5

The 11.50 version of Informix has been out of support for a long time; so has the 11.70 version which followed it. The standard advice is to upgrade, but I expect there are reasons why your company won't. You can try using the notation SELECT LIMIT 501 t.* FROM cxx99.ajmldm t mentioned earlier — that was supported before the notation you used was supported, but I'm not now sure whether that was part of 11.50 or not.

Although the client indicates 'Failed', I can connect to the database and use query statements normally. After searching for related issues, I found that these errors are actually maybe Warnings and won't affect our normal use of query statements. The solution is you can set the command SET client_min_messages TO ERROR; — is this operation correct?
This is the error message when connecting:
DBMS: Informix Dynamic Server (ver. 11.50.FC9)
Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=lower
Driver: Informix JDBC Driver for Informix Dynamic Server (ver. 4.50.JC10, JDBC4.2)
Ping: 187 ms
[01I01] Database has transactions.
[01I04] Database selected.


The information printed when connecting doesn't indicate any error. The 01I01 and 01I04 values for SQLCODE are informative rather than errors. Indeed, the fact that the code can identify that the database has transactions means it connected, and the "Database selected" message also indicates that the connection was successful. Also, you'd not get the -201 syntax error message if you'd been unable to connect to the database.
If there's something that allows you to configure the software you're using not to print warnings, or to treat printed warnings as errors, then that's probably a good way to go.  You shouldn't completely ignore warnings, but you should assess them carefully.
